# Htaccess recursive file rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, file, mod-rewrite, recursion

I would like to know if there is a better way to achieve this sort or redirection :

```
# Apache configuration

Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks


# Rewrite engine configuration

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


# Force domain www (302 redirect)

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+\.[^\.0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [L,R=302]


# Request redirection (/module/TLD/module/DOMAIN/module/SUB/data/public/...)

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.([^\.]+)\.([^\.0-9]+)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/module/%3/module/%2/module/%1/data/public/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)$        /module/%3/module/%2/module/%1/data/public/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.([^\.]+)\.([^\.0-9]+)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/module/%3/module/%2/module/%1/data/public/%{REQUEST_URI}/index.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)/?$        /module/%3/module/%2/module/%1/data/public/$1/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.([^\.]+)\.([^\.0-9]+)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/module/%3/module/%2/module/%1/data/public/%{REQUEST_URI}/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)/?$        /module/%3/module/%2/module/%1/data/public/$1/index.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.([^\.]+)\.([^\.0-9]+)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/module/%3/module/%2/module/%1/data/public/index.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?$            /module/%3/module/%2/module/%1/data/public/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.([^\.]+)\.([^\.0-9]+)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/module/%3/module/%2/module/%1/data/public/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^/?$            /module/%3/module/%2/module/%1/data/public/index.html [L]


# Request redirection (/module/TLD/module/DOMAIN/data/public/...)

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.+\.([^\.]+)\.([^\.0-9]+)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/module/%2/module/%1/data/public/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)$        /module/%2/module/%1/data/public/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.+\.([^\.]+)\.([^\.0-9]+)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/module/%2/module/%1/data/public/%{REQUEST_URI}/index.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)/?$        /module/%2/module/%1/data/public/$1/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.+\.([^\.]+)\.([^\.0-9]+)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/module/%2/module/%1/data/public/%{REQUEST_URI}/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)/?$        /module/%2/module/%1/data/public/$1/index.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.+\.([^\.]+)\.([^\.0-9]+)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/module/%2/module/%1/data/public/index.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?$            /module/%2/module/%1/data/public/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.+\.([^\.]+)\.([^\.0-9]+)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/module/%2/module/%1/data/public/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^/?$            /module/%2/module/%1/data/public/index.html [L]


# Request redirection (/module/TLD/data/public/...)

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.+\.([^\.0-9]+)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/module/%1/data/public/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)$        /module/%1/data/public/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.+\.([^\.0-9]+)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/module/%1/data/public/%{REQUEST_URI}/index.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)/?$        /module/%1/data/public/$1/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.+\.([^\.0-9]+)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/module/%1/data/public/%{REQUEST_URI}/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)/?$        /module/%1/data/public/$1/index.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.+\.([^\.0-9]+)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/module/%1/data/public/index.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?$            /module/%1/data/public/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.+\.([^\.0-9]+)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/module/%1/data/public/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^/?$            /module/%1/data/public/index.html [L]


# Request redirection (/data/public/...)

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/data/public/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)$        /data/public/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/data/public/%{REQUEST_URI}/index.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)/?$        /data/public/$1/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/data/public/%{REQUEST_URI}/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)/?$        /data/public/$1/index.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/data/public/index.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?$            /data/public/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/data/public/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^/?$            /data/public/index.html [L]


# Request redirection (main index file)

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L,PT]
```

For exemple, i redirect a request like `http://www.testdomain.com/test/file.css` to these possibles paths :

- `/module/com/module/testdomain/module/www/data/public/test/file.css`
- `/module/com/module/testdomain/data/public/test/file.css`
- `/module/com/data/public/test/file.css`
- `/data/public/test/file.css`

If none of these paths are correct, i fall back to `/index.php`. And, for a request with empty uri, i try to dispatch it like `http://www.testdomain.com/index.html` or `http://www.testdomain.com/index.php`. Is there a better way to achieve this sort of rewriting ?

Comment: You can compile the `index.php` and `index.html` paths into one using `index\.(php|html)` and refer it as a variable.

Comment: @hjpotter92, no you can't -- at least not for the first argument in a `Rewritecond` as this is a _string_ and not a _pattern_. :(

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is verbose and somewhat bizarre, and the bizarre nature is what caught my interest.  :-)  However, I assume that you must have your reasons.

One advantage of being verbose is that you can define exactly what you want to achieve and in one `.htaccess` file, so if it aint' broke ...   Though you are doing quite a few regexp and stat probes in this logic chain, so I am nore sure that I would recommend this as a general approach.

Also any 'options' would also impact the semantics of what you are trying to achieve, but you could use the recursive nature of the rewrite engine to advantage, for example if `/module/TLD/module/DOMAIN/module/SUB/data/public/` then the URI must be interpreted in that context, hence something like

```
# If we have a file match, then we're done
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  -f
RewriteRule ^                    -  [L]

# Skip the four directory rewrites except on first pass
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_PASS} !=""
RewriteRule ^                    -  [E:PASS=OK, SKIP=5]
RewriteRule ^                    -  [E:PASS=OK]

# Redirect to correct subdirectory
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^(.+)\.([^.]+)\.([^.\d]+)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/module/%3/module/%2/module/%1/data/public/   -d
RewriteRule ^.*$            /module/%3/module/%2/module/%1/data/public/$0  [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^.+\.([^.]+)\.([^.\d]+)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/module/%2/module/%1/data/public/             -d
RewriteRule ^.*$            /module/%2/module/%1/data/public/$0            [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^.+\.([^.\d]+)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/module/%1/data/public/                       -d
RewriteRule ^.*$            /module/%1/data/public/$0                     [L]

RewriteRule ^.*$           /data/public/$0                                [L]

# Etc ... your URIs now include the correct prefix.
```

Note

1. A bare `^` always matches
2. A bare `-` in the subst string means leave unchanged
3. Don't include leading `/` in PER_DIR (eg. `.htaccess` patterns
4. `$0` is the entire match string -- saves using brackets if you want the whole thing
5. You don't need to escape `.` inside a `[]` selector.
6. Read up on setting and using environment variables.  If you set the variable PASS then this appears as REDIRECT_PASS after an internal redirect.

You will also need to enable rewrite logging and go through your logs to debug this.  Have fun.

Comment: I know that is an uncommon rewriting usage ahah. Thank you for your response and notes !

Comment: After some tests. I have problem rewriting to `index.(php|html)` files in an existing directory. For exemple `/data/public/test/` is a directory, but i would like to redirect it to `/data/public/test/index.(php|html)` when the uri is `/test/`.

Comment: That's what [DirectoryIndex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) is for :)